# Firebase Firestore Get Document not working with Swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I want to try Firebase Cloud Firestore to get some data using the code below.

A button press should fetch a boolean value and if its meet some conditions the app will navigate to another view controller, it works fine on the first click but I noticed that when I navigate back and press the same button no result will be fetched again !!

```
db.collection("users").document((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).getDocument { (snap, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error.debugDescription)
                }
                if snap != nil {
                    let isPosted = snap?.data()["isPosted"] as! Bool
                    let isStroe = snap?.data()["isStore"] as! Bool
                    if !isPosted && !isStroe {
                        print("first post")
                        let useraccountVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newData") as! UINavigationController
                        self.present(useraccountVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }else if isPosted && isStroe {
                        print("store")
                        let useraccountVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newData") as! UINavigationController
                        self.present(useraccountVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }else if !isPosted && isStroe{
                        print("store")
                        let useraccountVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newData") as! UINavigationController
                        self.present(useraccountVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }else{

                        print("cant post any more")
                    }

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The pricing model [makes an explicit provision](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations) for this:

> Also, if the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as if you had issued a brand-new query.

This also applies to gets: if you repeat a get within 30 minutes and there are no changes there's no charge.

The way this works is that Firestore includes a "resume token" with queries to ask for changes since the last time it issued any given query.

You can verify that the client is sending a resume token for yourself by [enabling debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Firestore#enablelogging). When you make a query more than once, you'll see in the logs something like this for queries beyond the first:

```
Nov  1 16:44:36  Firestore_Example[8105] <Debug>: [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] FSTWatchStream 0x6080002cbc20 watch: <GCFSListenRequest 0x6180002cc010>: {
  database: "projects/my-project/databases/(default)"
  add_target {
    documents {
      documents: "projects/my-project/databases/(default)/documents/test-collection/c1GK3eq7rakmRvIN4ehE"
    }
    resume_token: "\n\t\010\254\251\304\242\307\236\327\002"
    target_id: 2
  }
}
```

If there aren't any changes on the server when you repeat the query you'll also be able to observe that despite making this second request, the responses won't actually transfer any documents, they'll just indicate that the client is up-to-date.

Comment: Ok, But my issue is i need that boolean values to do some functions ! even if the data is not changed on the server side

Comment: The data is always returned. If your document hasn't changed and you repeat your request in under 30 minutes, you won't be charged for the query that validates that the client is up-to-date is all.